# sympy: rearrange equation in terms of a variable

Tags: sympy

How can I make sympy keep the variable (and equals sign) after solving for a variable?

```
a,b = symbols('a b')
res = solveset( Eq(a+3,b), a)
print(res) #FiniteSetb-3
```

I want `res` to still be an equation, printing `a = b - 3`, but the above returns `FiniteSetb-3`.

Creating a new equation from the result does not work, implying that `a` is still in there(?).

```
res = Eq(a, solveset( Eq(a+3,b), a))
print(res) #False
```

Thanks